# How to solve the $p$th power of matrix $C$?

Tags: matrices, number-theory, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

> if $p\equiv1(mod3)$
> , $C=\left[
>   \begin{array}{ccc}
>     0 & 0 & 1 \\
>     1 & 0 & -3 \\
>     0 & 1 & -3 \\
>   \end{array}
> \right]\in M_3(\mathbb{F}_p).$
> How to calculate $C^p$?

I have tried some conventional methods, such as splitting the matrix, binomial theorem, etc. But got no result.

Do you have other good solutions? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: the significance of the $p \neq u^2 + 27 v^2$  is that $2$  is not a cube. There is no $n$   such that $n^3 \equiv 2 \pmod p.$

Comment: oh, well. See what you can do with $(I + C)^n$   for small $n.$  What is the characteristic polynomial of $I+C \; \; ? \; \; \;$

Comment: The idea/method with the comment by Will Jagy is to do a linear change of variables to simplify the polynomial $x^3 + 3x^2+3x-1$. For a different polynomial of degree $3$, I guess you would also first want to do a substitution to write it in the form $x^3 + ax + b$.

Comment: Reply to Will Jagy. The characteristic polynomial of $I+C$ is $f(x)=x^3-2$, but $p\equiv 1(mod3)$, $p\neq c^2+27d^2, c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$, it has no root in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: So, what are $(I+C)^3, (I+C)^6, $ and so on? Finally, expand $(I+C)^p $  modulo $p$

Comment: Reply to Will Jagy. Thanks a lot for your help, this question has been resolved. Tomorrow I will write about the problem solving process here. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is inspired by Will Jagy, I made some changes.

Let $A=I+C$, where $I$ is an identity matrix. It is easy to know
$$A= \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & -3 \\
    0 & 1 & -2 \\
  \end{array}
\right), A^3=2I.$$

Therefore $A^p=(I+C)^p=\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom {p}{k}I^{p-k}C^k=I+C^p$. Let $p=3m+1$, $m\in \mathrm{N}$, then $A^{3m+1}=I+C^p=(2I)^mA=2^m(I+C)$, i.e.
$$C^p=2^m(I+C)-I.$$